# Access the jwt token from multiple threads

Tags: jmeter, load-testing, jwt

I Have API's to retrieve the token and get Positions nested under 
**Token Generator** and **API Group** threads.

I need to retrieve token only once and set the token to the property and access it across multiple threads.

Reponse from the post request:

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMddiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX25hbWUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImxhc3RfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwiZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6OCwicm9sZSI6IkFETUlOIiwiaWF0IjoxNTg2NDQ3MTc2LCJleHAiOjE1OssdDY1MzM1NzZ9.Q9-DT0q7uR53prnZFw1cTFIAlhqzj-qzNwr3qCbFn5B4irAxkR469aGxQK5VhvfEoPk4R_jZwyOpERzmVcRI6A"}
```

[image]

> JSON Extractor in **Token Generator** thread

[image]

> BeanShell PostProcessor in **Token Generator** thread

```
props.put("token", jwt_token);
```

> HTTP Header Manager in **API Group** thread

```
Authorization : Bearer ${__P(token)}
```

but my request headers in second API:

```
Authorization: Bearer 1
```

What am i missing here?

Comment: Are you running both the thread in parallelly or one after another?

Comment: @Amol Sequentially

Comment: Karthik Suresh : Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your code in Beanshell Post Processor.

```
props.put("token", jwt_token);
```

You are trying to set a variable value in a property, but from the code, you have provided you are using `jwt_token` which is not the value extracted. You should update your code as below -

```
props.put("token", vars.get("jwt_token"));
```

Answer (score 0):

1. [Don't use Beanshell, starting from JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting
2. You can avoid this JSON Extractor bit and perform the extraction of the JWT token and storing it into a JMeter property in a single line of code to wit:

   ```
   props.put('token', new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(prev.getResponseData()).token)
   ```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)